# Can i use the ,Net Dll in Android Application

Tags: android, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0

is android app compatible with .net dlls. if it is compitable so how we can use the .net dll with Android apps

Comment: Not without the help of something like Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

In general case no! To use .NET over Android you should use Xamarin https://www.xamarin.com/platform . The main problem is that Android apps generally uses JVM & Java stack, and .NET in the same time has it's own structure. so, in case of Xamarin your Java stack is being temporary "changed" to mono engine:
[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5kgs.png)